# Bulk Insert Formatting Issue from CSV File

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I am doing a bulk insert from a CSV file.

In one of my columns, I am using a colon such as this 36:21.0.  For every row in this column I am getting the following error:

```
"Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 11, column 3 (MyColumnName)."
```

Does anyone know a workaround to this so that I will be able to bulk insert the columns that have a colon in the data along with the rest of my columns?

Here is my query if you are interested:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.[PropertyDefinition] FROM 
'//MY CSV FILE PATH HERE'
WITH(
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        DATAFILETYPE ='char',
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'            
    )
```

Comment: Check previous columns in row 11. Do they contain comma(s)? Also it is good idea to use formatfile (xml format file is my preference).

Comment: Thanks.  Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct.

I don't think that colon is causing the problem because the field-terminator and row-terminator does not include colon.

This problem is usually caused due to data type miss-match in the file and the table.

Just make sure that the datatype you are giving for column 3 is matching with the datatype of data in the file at row 11, column 3.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  The CSV file that I am pulling from is pulling an older datetime2 format than what the table is expecting.  The table is expecting current datetime2.  I'm pretty sure this is the cause of this error.  I will keep digging.  Thanks for clarifying the colon is ok to use like this.